# Iterating on mutable collections being mutated

Tags: scala, scala-collections

It the behavior of obtaining an `Iterator` on a mutable collection (via `.iterator`), modifying the collection and then iterating with the previously-obtained iterator well-defined? In particular for a `mutable.Map`?

In general, is it possible to iterate and modify a mutable collection at the same time? I'm not talking about multithreading here.

I was not able to find anything in the Scala documentation. In C++, such cases are well defined and it depends on the type of container and the type of operation performed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap(
  1 -> 1,
  2 -> 2,
  3 -> 3
)

val it1 = m.iterator
val it2 = m.iterator

println(it1.next)          // prints  (2,2)
println(it1.next)          // prints  (1,1)

m update(1, 4)

it1.foreach(println)      // prints  (3,3)
it2.foreach(println)      // prints  (2,2), (1,4) and (3,3)
```

For HashMap it's clear. The iterator is still valid after the update (`it2`) if you of course haven't stepped over the updated values (`it1`)

But it behaves completely different for `LinkedList` and `ArrayBuffer`, each.

So yes, this kinda works, no, not everywhere as expected. 
My advice would be to go for `map` and `foreach` and even omit mutable structures.

Comment: It's not super clear to me what the conclusion is.  Most of the answer seems to support "yes it will work", but at the end you say that each iterator works differently and although some might seem to work, it's not something you can rely on in general.

Comment: Since the questions were "[…] is it possible to iterate and modify a mutable collection at the same time?" and "Is the behavior of obtaining an Iterator […], modifying the collection and then iterating with the previously-obtained iterator well-defined?" My answers are "Yes it works" and "No, it's not well defined". 
And fair enough, I gave advice that wasn't asked. I just thought that might help.

Comment: It kinds works in this example, but it could be just by chance. I think it's not well defined, so unreliable, so it should not be done. I just wanted to know if some collection promise to support it or it's just left unspecified, so risky.

Comment: @ragazzojp At this point I honestly don't know about how it is specified. Especially since I'm mostly working with immutables. But what I can tell you is that even the immutable collections are not well defined, at all.